# Can't log in to TFS (Team Foundation Service) using my Microsoft account

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

When I try to log in to TFS (Team Foundation Service) it's redirecting back me to the login interface again and again but others are able to access using their accounts through my computer. My Microsoft account is also working fine. This is happening only for one project which is hosted in TFS and I have tried by re-adding me in to the project through the project admin as a member but no use. My computer is up to date and all the needed components and service packs are installed in it also it is running Win.7 (others are able to access using their accounts through my computer).

How can I solve this problem ?